# How can I add an existing directory to pydev?

Tags: python, git, github, pydev

I have a functioning folder full of python code that I wrote. I want Eclipse to edit and run it using PyDev. I tried altering some existing .pydevproject and .project files. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: right click on the folder, then choose "Open Project".